# 'Project is not associated to SonarQube' is shown when associating and running a code coverage tool (SonarQube) in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sonarqube

I am using Android Studio for android application development. I have to use a code coverage tool to test the effectivness of my jUnit test cases. I checked in Android Studio plugin repository and installed SonarQube code coverage tool. I have added it as a plugin to build.gradle file as well .

Now, the issue that I am facing is that when I run this tool from Android Studio(Analyze->Inspect Code), it shows all the error statistics for-Android Lint, Code style errors, Probable Imports, Error Handling, General etc. 
However, It does not show any info regarding number of lines of code analyzed.

Also, the SonarQube console shows that 'Project is not associated to SonarQube',and when I try to associate my project , a dialog box appears that shows no project to associate with.

Please provide help regarding the same.
Thanks